# S3 Class plot method conflicting with package methods

Tags: r, glmnet

I have a collection of R scripts that define an S3 class which searches large covariate spaces using different methods, model types, and cost functions.  In order to visualize the progress of the search, I have some class specific plot methods defined and I use method dispatch to make sure the classes see the right functions.  Specifically, I have plot methods defined as `plot.fs_forward_model`, etc.  I also have a file with the method dispatch functions defined as, for example, `plot = function(x, ...) UseMethod('plot', x)`

That's all great and my set of classes work very well in this manner.  But, when I'm using glmnet and I want to create a plot of the lasso results, I get an error that appears to stem from my method dispatch line.   The traceback looks like this:

```
4 stop("'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'") 
3 xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) 
2 plot.default(llr) at FS_MethodDispatch.R#14
1 plot(llr)
```

with line 1 being my call to plot for the glmnet object resulting from a call to glmnet, i.e, `llr=glmnet(x, y, family='gaussian')`

Any tips on how to make sure my method dispatch doesn't interfere with other packages are greatly appreciated.

Comment: `plot` is already defined as `UseMethod('plot')`, why are you doing it again?

Comment: Your question is essentially an answer to my question.  When I was working through this, I had assumed I needed to have a UseMethod('plot') statement, but clearly that is not the case.  I would click this as an answer and upvote you, but I can't do that for a comment.